# How to pass data in collections for Chart JS in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, chart.js

I would like to use helpers to get the wanted data from collections and load these data into a chart(chart.js). Now, I don’t know how to properly define and pass these data from helpers to onrendered hanlder, since I got these two errors:`Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:` and `ReferenceError: data is not defined`

```
import './visual.html';
import { subject,student,record } from '../../lib/collections/collection.js';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

Template.charts.helpers({
  charts:function(){
//To get the attendance rate for each student who has been attended classes
    var studentIDList =[];
    var studentArray = [];
    var numOfStudent = student.find().count();
    var studentDoc = student.find().fetch();

    for(let i = 0; i<numOfStudent; i++){
      studentIDList.push(studentDoc[i].studentID);
    }

    for(let x = 0; x<numOfStudent; x++){
      let item = studentIDList[ x ],
          exist = record.findOne({studentID:item});
      if(!exist){
        //console.log("Student record not found");
      }else{
        studentArray.push(item);

      }
    }
    var data =[];
    for(let x = 0;x<studentArray.length; x++){
      let totalRecord = record.find({studentID:studentArray[x]}).count(),
          attend = record.find({studentID:studentArray[x],attendance:true}).count(),
          rate = attend/totalRecord;
      data.push({
        x:studentArray[x],
        y:rate
      });
    }
    return data;
  }

Template.charts.onRendered(function () {
  console.log("The Bar Chart is rendered")
  let ctx = $("#myChart");
  this.autorun(() => {
    let myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type   : 'bar',
      data   : data,
      options: barChartOptions
  });
});

});
});
```

HTML

```
<template name="charts">
  <div style="width:800px; height:500px;">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
```

The data I want to pass looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You prepare the "data" inside helper - but do never call that function. You place "new Chart" inside autorun() what will re-calc always the Chart on changing data.
Just for a test and get you closer to your expectations: place the helper function content  inside onRendered and move newChart also outside autorun(). The graph should be shown once.

Comment: @TomFreudenberg After doing as you told, it is still not working. The array that I want to pass became empty.

Comment: Please post your collection.js. Have you content in that collections? Do you able to get that data on another form alreay?